# How do I host multiple SSL websites using ISA inbound rules with 1 external IP address?

Tags: ssl, isa-server

How do I host multiple SSL websites(all subdomains) using ISA inbound rules with 1 external IP address?

I think something like [option 2 in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/81004/multiple-ssl-services-using-single-ip-address-or-multiple-dhcp-on-single-interfac) might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using a wildcard or SAN cert, you will need to set up SSL Host Headers on IIS: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html

Answer (score 2):

At the minimum you will need a server certificate which supports wildcards (if both of the hostnames are under the same DNS domain) or a certificate with more than one name (if not.)

Once you have that, the remaining should be pretty easy.

Comment: +1, you need 1 IP per Cert; so the Cert has to cover all the possible domains people will connect to.